# large dataset on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, pre-trained-model

I try to extract sentiment for very large dataset that consists of more than 606912 instances on Jupyter notebook, but it takes several days and interrupted this my code:

```
from camel_tools.sentiment import SentimentAnalyzer

sentiment_dataset=pd.DataFrame()
full_text=[]
sa = SentimentAnalyzer("CAMeL-Lab/bert-base-arabic-camelbert-da-sentiment")
full_text =  dataset['clean_text'].tolist()
iter_len = len(full_text)
for e in range(iter_len):
    print("Iterate through list:",full_text[e])
    s = sa.predict(full_text[e])
    sentiments.insert(e, s)
    print("Iterate through sentiments list:",sentiments[e])
dataset['sentiments']=pd.DataFrame(sentiments)
```

can someone help me to solve this issue or speed up the operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not too efficient to proceed one big source dataset in one python instance. My recommendation are:

**Version 1. - use our own parallelization**

- split the big source dataset to smaller parts
- run the same code in more instances (processes) for increase parallelization with focus on smaller parts of original dataset
- run this code directly from command line

**Version 2. - use existing solution for parallelization**

- install e.g. Apache Spark, Polaris, etc. and use parallel execution in this one
- see short performance comparing https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/